# The questions about Spark dataframe operations

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

if I create a dataframe like this:

```
val df1 = sc.parallelize(List((1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 2), (2, 3)).toDF("key1","key2")
```

Then I group by "key1" and "key2", and  count "key2".

```
val df2 = df1.groupBy("key1","key2").agg(count("key2") as "k").sort(col("k").desc)
```

My question is how to filter this dataframe and leave the top 2 num of the "k" from each "key1"?

---

if I don't use window functions ,what should I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using window-function, using `row_number()` (or also `rank()`/`dense_rank()`, depending on your requirements):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.row_number
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

df2
  .withColumn("rnb", row_number().over(Window.partitionBy($"key1").orderBy($"k".desc)))
  .where($"rnb" <= 2).drop($"rnb")
  .show()
```

EDIT:

Here a solution using RDD (which do not require a HiveContext):

```
df2
  .rdd
  .groupBy(_.getAs[Int]("key1"))
  .flatMap{case (_,rows) => {
    rows.toSeq
      .sortBy(_.getAs[Long]("k")).reverse
      .take(2)
      .map{case Row(key1:Int,key2:Int,k:Long) => (key1,key2,k)}
   }
 }
.toDF("key1","key2","k")
.show()
```

Comment: it informs:ERROR ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Could not resolve window function 'row_number'. Note that, using window functions currently requires a HiveContext;

Comment: How to solve this? thx!! my spark version is 1.6

Comment: @RyanWang as the Error indicates, you need to create a `HiveContext`, an `SQLContext` is not sufficient

Comment: @RyanWang I added a solution wihtout Window-Function